# Chef: Error executing action `run` on resource 'redisio_configure[redis-servers]'

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I got the following error during installation Redis by Chef using recipe redisio. Could you help me find a reason

```
Recipe: redisio::configure
   * redisio_configure[redis-servers] action run

     ================================================================================
     Error executing action `run` on resource 'redisio_configure[redis-servers]'
     ================================================================================

     TypeError
     ---------
     no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String

     Cookbook Trace:
     ---------------
     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/providers/configure.rb:87:in `+'
     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/providers/configure.rb:87:in `block in configure'
     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/providers/configure.rb:38:in `each'
     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/providers/configure.rb:38:in `configure'
     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/providers/configure.rb:22:in `block in class_from_file'

     Resource Declaration:
     ---------------------
     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/configure.rb

      30: redisio_configure "redis-servers" do
      31:   version redis['version'] if redis['version']
      32:   default_settings redis['default_settings']
      33:   servers redis_instances
      34:   base_piddir redis['base_piddir']
      35: end
      36: 

     Compiled Resource:
     ------------------
     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/configure.rb:30:in `from_file'

     redisio_configure("redis-servers") do
       action :run
       retries 0
       retry_delay 2
       default_guard_interpreter :default
       declared_type :redisio_configure
       cookbook_name "redisio"
       recipe_name "configure"
       version "2.8.17"
       default_settings {"user"=>"redis", "group"=>"redis", "homedir"=>"/redis", "shell"=>"/bin/sh", "systemuser"=>true, "ulimit"=>0, "configdir"=>"/etc/redis", "name"=>nil, "address"=>nil, "databases"=>"16", "backuptype"=>"rdb", "datadir"=>"/var/lib/redis", "unixsocket"=>nil, "unixsocketperm"=>nil, "timeout"=>"0", "keepalive"=>"0", "loglevel"=>"notice", "logfile"=>nil, "syslogenabled"=>"yes", "syslogfacility"=>"local0", "shutdown_save"=>false, "save"=>nil, "stopwritesonbgsaveerror"=>"yes", "slaveof"=>nil, "masterauth"=>nil, "slaveservestaledata"=>"yes", "replpingslaveperiod"=>"10", "repltimeout"=>"60", "requirepass"=>"password", "maxclients"=>"512", "maxmemory"=>"1073741824", "maxmemorypolicy"=>nil, "maxmemorysamples"=>nil, "appendfsync"=>"everysec", "noappendfsynconrewrite"=>"no", "aofrewritepercentage"=>"100", "aofrewriteminsize"=>"64mb", "luatimelimit"=>"5000", "slowloglogslowerthan"=>"10000", "slowlog-max-len"=>"1024", "notifykeyspaceevents"=>"", "hashmaxziplistentries"=>"512", "hashmaxziplistvalue"=>"64", "setmaxintsetentries"=>"512", "zsetmaxziplistentries"=>"128", "zsetmaxziplistvalue"=>"64", 
"activerehasing"=>"yes", "clientoutputbufferlimit"=>[["normal", "0", "0", "0"], ["slave", "256mb", "64mb", "60"], ["pubsub", "32mb", "8mb", "60"]], "hz"=>"10", "aofrewriteincrementalfsync"=>"yes", "cluster-enabled"=>"no", "cluster-config-file"=>nil, "cluster-node-timeout"=>5, "includes"=>nil, "maxmemory-policy"=>"volatile-lru"}
       servers [{"port"=>"6379"}]
       base_piddir "/var/run/redis"
     end


 Running handlers:
 [2016-01-22T09:38:44+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
 Running handlers complete
 [2016-01-22T09:38:44+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
 Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated in 12 seconds
 [2016-01-22T09:38:44+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
 [2016-01-22T09:38:44+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
 [2016-01-22T09:38:44+00:00] ERROR: redisio_configure[redis-servers] (redisio::configure line 30) had an error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
 [2016-01-22T09:38:44+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have `"maxclients"=>"512"`, with the value as a string. That is supposed to be an integer, i.e. `"maxclients"=>512`. Fix it in your node attributes.